# How to style css of scrollbar at the root level?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, frontend

```css
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: var(--scroll-thumb-color);
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: var(--scroll-back-color);
    width: 5px;
  }
}
```

The styles placed at the `body`, as above, has no effect on the top level scrollbar.

How to fix it?

Comment: as a guess ... target the style at the top level rather than the body - by the way, that's not CSS in the question, is it

Comment: just put everything (excluding overflow-y:scroll ) to out of body{}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selectors don't seem to be correct.

If you're using SASS it should be:

```
body {
  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: var(--scroll-thumb-color);
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: var(--scroll-back-color);
    width: 5px;
  }
}
```

or if you're using plain CSS:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: var(--scroll-thumb-color);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: var(--scroll-back-color);
  width: 5px;
}
```